# Redirect from within routes.rb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, redirect, routes

I'm creating a history of name changes for records in my database. So if someone changes the name of something they own, old URLS still work.

I'm trying something like this:

```
get '/:id', to: "services#show", as: 'show_service', constraints: lambda {|request|
  urls = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  if urls.include? params[:id]
    puts "Yep - this works."
    return redirect latest_url
  else
    # Nothing matches, this service doesn't exist.
    return false
  end
}
```

Two ways for this route to complete:

1. WORKING: It finds nothing and returns false so the route execution order continues down.
2. NOT WORKING: It finds something and redirect to the latest name in the route history.

That return redirect latest_url isn't redirecting at all - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since the tests against each route stop on the first match, it's simpler to have two routes:

```
# legacy name support
get '/:id', to: redirect(latest_url), constraints: lambda { |request|
  urls = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  urls.include? request.params[:id]
}

# latest and greatest
get '/:id', to: "services#show", as: 'show_service'
```

PS: I'd also suggest this is complex enough to warrant it's own class that responds to `matches?` instead of the inline lambda, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

PPS: depending on the complexity of your use-case, it's worth taking a look at the **friendly_id** gem and it's *history* module.